# Bootstrap input-group textarea with button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a simple submit input group. I currently have the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">                            
                                        <span>Send</span>

    </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want the 'Send' button to take up the entire height of the text area. Is this doable?

Comment: Don't miss your ">" closing statement:  style="resize:none"></textarea>

Answer (score 94, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `input-group-addon` utility. This will allow the space of the button to take up the entire height. You will need to adjust the fill because it only works on hover (the color change). I'd recommend copying all the relevant class styles and make your own (for the color and background color so it's not the default Bootstrap style).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>     
    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Send</span>
</div>
```

I know it's not in line with Bootstrap documentation, but their documentation assumes you aren't using a textarea.

Comment: Can't I change button size?

Comment: @Aibrean You should change the bootstrap link to http**s**. Recent versions of Chrome blocks http content on https sites.

Comment: Also add tabindex="0" to the span tag to be able to navigate with the keyboard. Like: <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">Send</span>

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Aibrean's answer and to further clarify how to make his/her `span` tag operable.

We will need to bind the span to an event listener, in the example below I use jQuery.

```js
; (function ($) {
  $('#submitMyForm').on('click', function () {
    //$('#myForm').submit(); // js fiddle won't allow this
    alert("form submitted");
  });
  
})(jQuery)
```

```css
#exampleWrapper {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="exampleWrapper">
  <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="?process-form">
      <div class="input-group">
          <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" id="submitMyForm">Send</span>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets suppose we want to create a textarea with a GO button at the left(at the start) and the search sign at the right(end).
here is the code to do so using bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>
Creating a button in text area using bootstrap        
</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">


<label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>


</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```